# Incluir texto de otro documento con la función fwrite (PHP)

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo en PHP que imprime unas líneas de código a través de la función fwrite. El tema es que las 10 primeras líneas de código las quiero imprimir manualmente, pero a continuación quiero imprimir otras 700 líneas de código que ya tengo en un fichero aparte y no quiero tener que escribir línea a línea el código a imprimir.

En resumen, me gustaría concatenar a la función fwrite una especie de función que me imprima a continuación todo el contenido del otro documento.

```
<?php

require_once ("config_examen.php");
$ar=fopen("fichero.txt","w") or die("Error");

fwrite($ar, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>');
fwrite($ar, "\n");
fwrite($ar, '<key>hashedQuitPassword</key>');
fwrite($ar, "\n")
fwrite($ar, '<string>' . $password_hashed . '</string>');
fwrite($ar, "\n");

***AQUÍ QUIERO CONCATENAR EL CONTENIDO DEL DOCUMENTO B****

?>
```

¿Se os ocurre algún método? Muchas gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Intenta algo con https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php y, si no te sale, amplía la pregunta con el error que obtengas y podremos ayudarte. ¡Ánimo!

Comment: No entiendo cuál es tu dificultad. Donde quieres concatenar el contenido del documento B, abre el documento B y muestra su contenido ¿no?

Comment: Sisi pero era eso precisamente lo que no sabía hacer. Con la solución de @David JP he podido lograrlo. Muchas gracias.